# Angular Firebase not receiving messages

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive a message in my angular app via the firebase using [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/fb269959f32fbd987d5e67619dcd4cd289310365/docs/messaging/messaging.md) yet I fail to succeed.

I have added `firebase-messaging-sw.js` with below content and added it to `angular.json`

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xx",
  projectId: "xx",
  storageBucket: "xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Also imported all in module:

```
 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
    // declarations
  ],
 imports: [
    //other modules...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireMessagingModule
  ]
```

Finally i created a simple component to test my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-firebase',
  template: `
    <button (click)="requestPermission()">
      Request perms
    </button>
    <button (click)="listen()">
      Get notified!
    </button>
  `

})
export class FirebaseComponent {

  constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
  }

  requestPermission() {
    this.afMessaging.requestToken
      .subscribe(
        token => console.log(`Permission granted! Save to the server! \n${token}`),
        error => console.log(error.toString()),
      );
  }

  listen() {
    console.log('Subscribed');
    this.afMessaging.messages
      .subscribe((message) => {
        console.log(message);
      });
  }
}
```

It seems it is able to request the token however I do not get any message when I try to send a test message from firebase dashboard (notice lack of any result from `console.log(message)`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the reason was the missing manifest.json. Once I have added it it seems to work